# Should std::future::wait be using so much CPU? Is there a more performant call?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

**EDIT: tl;dr -- this problem appears to be limited to a small set of OS/compiler/library combinations and is now tracked in the GCC Bugzilla as [Bug 68921](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68921) thanks to [@JonathanWakely](https://stackoverflow.com/users/981959/jonathan-wakely).**

I'm waiting on a future and I've noticed that `top` shows 100% CPU usage and `strace` shows a steady stream of `futex` calls:

```
...
[pid 15141] futex(0x9d19a24, FUTEX_WAIT, -2147483648, {4222429828, 3077922816}) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
...
```

This is on Linux 4.2.0 (32-bit `i686`), compiled with gcc version 5.2.1.

Here is my minimum-viable example program:

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  std::promise<void> p;
  auto f = p.get_future();

  std::thread t([&p](){
    std::cout << "Biding my time in a thread.\n";
    sleep(10);
    p.set_value();
  });

  std::cout << "Waiting.\n";
  f.wait();
  std::cout << "Done.\n";

  t.join();
  return 0;
}
```

and here is the compiler invocation (same behavior without `-g`):

```
g++ --std=c++11 -Wall -g -o spin-wait spin-wait.cc -pthread
```

**Is there a more-performant alternative?**

Here is a logically-similar program using `std::condition_variable` that seems to perform *much* better:

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  bool done = 0;
  std::mutex m;
  std::condition_variable cv;

  std::thread t([&m, &cv, &done](){
    std::cout << "Biding my time in a thread.\n";
    sleep(10);
    {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
      done = 1;
    }
    cv.notify_all();
  });

  std::cout << "Waiting.\n";
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
    cv.wait(lock, [&done]{ return done; });
  }
  std::cout << "Done.\n";

  t.join();
  return 0;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong with my `std::future`-based code, or is the implementation in my `libstdc++` just that bad?

Comment: Maybe you should find out why `futex` is being called with an invalid argument, and fix it...

Comment: I bet somewhere there's code like `while(!future_is_done) futex(...);` where they're expecting the call to `futex` to wait for a while, but if it fails it ends up accidentally being an infinite loop.

Comment: (And since it's not in your code, you've probably found a standard library bug)

Comment: i wanted to give the Internet a chance to tell me just how wrong my code was before assuming it was someone else's bug, but yeah, it does feel like `libstdc++` either has a bug or makes some sort of unstated assumption.

Comment: Looks like a bug in libstdc++ or kernel, or some funny problem with your environment configuration. Your program works for me without spinning on Linux 4.3.2, compiled by GCC 4.9.3 or 5.3.0. Does it spin without strace intervening?

Comment: I assume so - I only started looking with strace once I noticed it taking 100% in `top`.

Comment: Well, technically you have a data race between `set_value` and `get_future` (see [LWG 2412](http://wg21.link/LWG2412)).

Comment: Oh. Gross. What is the point of the futures library if this doesn't work?

Comment: I can see how LWG 2412's example has a race between `get_future` and `set_value`, but would it still if they got the future before launching the thread, like `std::promise<void> p; auto f = p.get_future(); std::thread t{ [&f]{ f.wait(); }}; p.set_value(); t.join();` ?

Comment: Yes, getting the future before starting the thread removes the race.

Comment: @T.C. - thanks! will edit.

Comment: both versions seem happy (not eating 100% cpu) on osx yosemite 10.10.5 w/ Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81) compiled as `c++ -std=c++11 -o spin-wait spin-wait.cc`

Comment: @ConstantinBaranov neither appears to spin-wait for me either on Linux 3.13.0 (under osx VMware) compiled with gcc version 4.8.4. Guess it's a specific-version bug. I'm guessing it's gcc 5.2.1 rather than linux 4.2.0, but it would be nice to hear either from someone who can reproduce it or from someone with one of those (not both) who can't.

Comment: of possible interest, the bad environment is 32-bit and both of my good environments are 64-bit.

Comment: Works fine on mingw-w64 gcc 5.2 and VS2015 :)

Comment: linux 4.2.0 (ubuntu 15.10), g++5.2.1, 64-bit, no noticeable cpu usage here.

Comment: @RobStarling Did you confirm the bug after you removed the data race?

Comment: @Yakk yes - still 100% CPU, still thousands of `futex(0x9aefa24, FUTEX_WAIT, -2147483648, {1319486337, 3968008193}) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)`

Comment: @dyp ooh -- that's interesting! do you have the requisite library support to try compiling with `-m32` to see what happens with a 32-bit binary?

Comment: @RobStarling Indeed, `-m32` and I can reproduce the issue you're describing: 100 % cpu usage and a lot of futex waits.

Comment: @dyp yay, i'm not crazy! boo, it's a bug. thanks! anyone else have a (newer) 32-bit environment to try?

Comment: I can reproduce it on 32-bit. I guess I'd better fix it. The problem is the TODO line in `atomic_futex.h` so I guess it needs to be done.

Comment: @Yakk, the data race was only ever theoretical, i.e. it was present according to the standard, not not in reality. My implementation in GCC (and probably all other implementations) never had an actual data race there. The LWG issue proposes fixing the wording to standardising existing practice.

Comment: @RobStarling, a minimum-viable program defines `int main()` if it doesn't use `argc` and `argv`. I never understand why people don't make their minimum test cases warning-free ;)

Comment: Correction: fixing the TODO would just hide the problem, the invalid argument is the real problem.

Comment: @JonathanWakely wait, are you saying that the error message actually described the error?

Comment: @JonathanWakely corrected. thanks.

Comment: @JonathanWakely incidentally, what flags gave you a warning? `-Wall` didn't say anything for me.

Comment: This is now https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68921 - the loop that keeps calling `futex(2)` is at https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/atomic_futex.h;h=90317f2d013e3f9ce27daab83798036a828e2608;hb=HEAD#l84

Comment: @RobStarling `-Wextra` does warn (because it turns on `-Wunused-parameter`)

Comment: @JonathanWakely thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No of course it shouldn't be doing that, it's a bug in the implementation, not a property of `std::future`.

This is now https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68921 - the loop that keeps calling `futex(2)` is in [`__atomic_futex_unsigned::_M_load_and_test_until`](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/atomic_futex.h;h=90317f2d013e3f9ce27daab83798036a828e2608;hb=HEAD#l84)

It looks like a simple missing argument to the `syscall` function, so a garbage pointer is passed to the kernel, which complains that it's not a valid `timespec*` argument. I'm testing the fix and will commit tomorrow, so it will be fixed in GCC 5.4

Comment: @TemplateRex, that doesn't seem like a directly relevant comment for this answer. See https://gcc.gnu.org/develop.html which explains documentation and regression fixes only. Exceptions can be made for serious non-regression bugs, or trivial fixes that pose no risk of breaking the release branch (but not just because someone pings it). It is entirely in line with the policy that something fixed on trunk is not automatically fixed on a release branch, so you should not be surprised by that. The feature freeze for gcc 5 was November 2014! That fix does look simple, but I don't know if it's safe.

Answer (score 0):

*No, it should not. It usually works great.*

(In the comments, we're trying to determine more about a specific broken configuration in which the resultant executable appears to spin-wait, but I believe that's the answer. It would still be nice to determine if this is still a spin-wait on a 32-bit target in the latest g++.)

> The [promise](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise) is the "push" end of the promise-future communication channel: the operation that stores a value in the shared state synchronizes-with (as defined in `std::memory_order`) the successful return from any function that is waiting on the shared state (such as `std::future::get`).

I assume this includes `std::future::wait`.

> [[`std::promise::set_value`]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise/set_value) Atomically stores the value into the shared state and makes the state ready.
>   The operation behaves as though `set_value`, `set_exception`, `set_value_at_thread_exit`, and `set_exception_at_thread_exit` acquire a single mutex associated with the promise object while updating the promise object.

While it's a little unsettling that they describe the synchronization in terms of the promise object and not the shared-state, the intent is pretty clear.

cppreference.com[[*]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise) goes on to use it in exactly the way that wasn't working in the question above. ("This example shows how promise can be used as signals between threads.")

Comment: I don't find it unsettling, since the shared state is associated with that promise at the time of the call, and a shared state can only be associated with one promise at a time, and the mutex is only needed by operations on the promise, not by the readers waiting on the same shared state.

Comment: got it. the mutex comment means only one thing can interact with the promise to make the state ready and the synchronizes-with comment means that anything waiting on the state sees the value.

Comment: Right, that mutex (which doesn't have to actually exist, as long as the implementation behaves as though it did) is used to serialize calls to the set_xxx functions. Most operations on the shared state are required to be atomic w.r.t readers and writers, but this is an operation on (or at least "through") the promise.